# Ubuntu 16, Mysql 2.7, and multiple instances through systemd

Tags: mysql, services, systemd, multiple-instances

I'm trying to set up multiples instances of MySQL following the *Configuring Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd* section of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances) manual page.

It seems pretty straight forward. I edited `mysql.cnf` to look like this:

```
[mysqld@replica01]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica01
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica01/mysql.sock
port=3307
log-error=/var/log/mysqld-replica01.log

[mysqld@replica02]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica02
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica02/mysql.sock
port=3308
log-error=/var/log/mysqld-replica02.log
```

I also created `mysqld@replica01.service` and `mysqld@replica02.service` files using copies of `mysql.service` and enabled both `mysqld@replica01` and `mysqld@replica02` via

```
systemctl enable mysqld@replica01
```

I can start either but they both start up with default settings (port 3306 for instance).
I assumed that MySQL would match the service name with the configuration group in `mysql.cnf` but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Has any one successfully configured multiple instances this way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem, [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,649641,649641#msg-649641). I've created the new service files but can't even get the services to start. Have you made any progress with this since you posted it?

Comment: I have not gotten multiple instances of MySQL to start at boot through systemd by adding named groups to the _my.cnf_ file. No.

I ended up getting multiple instances to start up by creating multiple _my.cnf_ files, specifying unique socket, PID, and ports values therein, storing each file in its own directory and creating one systemd unit file per instance and specifying the path to the appropriate configuration file using an environment variable to change the value of MYSQL_HOME.

I'd still like to figure out how the MySQL intended the named groups (mysqld@replica01) solution to work.

Comment: Note that the devs have confirmed that it hasn't been implemented in the DEB packages yet: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82785